# Tor stuck at 10 % Bootstrap

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vidalia, bootstrapping

I don't know why but my Tor can't seem to establish an encrypted directory connection. And when I see the logs it shows this warning "Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10 % : Connecting to directory server". I am accessing the Tor from my university internet and I have even used the latest version of Tor with pluggable transport but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely means that your university's network are blocking vanilla Tor. To circumvent this, use meek-amazon pluggable transport which works by making your Tor traffic look like you're trying to access Amazon's CDN services, or use obfs4, or snowflake (to be available soon).

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your university is blocking all connections to Tor. Depending on what you intend to do, you may have some options.

Option 1: If you just want to circumvent university censorship, you may try few free VPN and see if they work from your environment. If they work you either can use them or connect to Tor through them for example to connect to hidden services.

Option 2: Use Tails and figure out if it works from your environment. Tails is a live CD/USB operating system preconfigured to use Tor safely.

Option 3: Use JAP/JonDo free service and see if it works.

Option 4: Explain in details, how you connect to internet from your environment. For example, do you have to log in with username and password, provide as much detail as you can so that we can give you a custom solution.

Option 4: You may choose additional bridges above and beyond what comes as a default with Tor browser. You may find them at https://bridges.torproject.org/?transport=obfs2

Comment: I use a proxy to connect through the university's internet. No username or password required. As for free VPN they have blocked everything. What is Tails?

Comment: @user3772366, I edited the answer to explain what Tails is.

Comment: @user3772366, I further edited the answer to comply with your environment. Do not forget to set the proxy in TB if required.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(  Tails is blocked and for some reason no bridges work (even the one I receive in mail) to block so many bridges is it possible? Even pluggable transports aren't working

Comment: @user3772366, Dear, Try option 3 and see if it is working.