# Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay

Tags: relays, obfsproxy

While settting up my relay, I met this question:

```
Jan 19 10:02:22.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 51; recommendation warn; host 24E2F139121D4394C54B5BCC368B3B411857C413 at 204.13.164.118:443)
Jan 19 10:02:22.000 [warn] 51 connections have failed:
Jan 19 10:02:22.000 [warn]  32 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
Jan 19 10:02:22.000 [warn]  18 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

I had read [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/14188/28505), but I have set up obfs4. What's going wrong?

.torrc

```
SocksPort 0
Log notice file ~/tor-notices.log
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 443
Exitpolicy reject *:*
BridgeRelay 1
# PublishServerDescriptor 0
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 [::]:2048
ExtORPort auto
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your tor is misconfigured.. (or I am misunderstanding)

Are you trying to run a bridge relay? Or do you mean to specify that you want to use bridges, to establish a connection to the onion network through stringent conditions?

```
SocksPort 9050
Log notice file ~/tor-notices.log
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 443
Exitpolicy reject *:*

#BridgeRelay 1
UseBridges 1

# PublishServerDescriptor 0
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy
#ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 [::]:2048
ExtORPort auto

Bridge obfs4 88.193.235.54:52313 13499A6677D38C132DB84A5BCC841A61210B2491 cert=0TC1Ul9jW1nCALKm5pKYcrrKoZm/ttDvbMsf0qJ9SyhhHSlXwpbrJUeFYiHAtjptMRpAXw iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 175.211.109.73:443 7561F8F902957490421282F3D12F81F8115B9AF9 cert=WFJBHYP/MYBU9bgPkU/JqIxZfz9RHiBA+tSZpVtofIUzgItq7bi14lqKQb85csCWQsKsYQ iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 72.19.15.147:443 F12E59AA3EF26CFF4623D379E8358617BB24C1F6 cert=vhf1NSQL3A1dsi+yNAGHmrMHZmBkJRacSrofqqP9QM1tVW/qh1nAY9Q4JCWwvC81AMwNYg iat-mode=0
```

If you wish to obtain your own bridges, visit [bridges.torproject.org](https://bridges.torproject.org/). The above were just obtained from there now.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue,  and I did try obs and meek, here are logs

### without bridge

updating settings in Tor service

updating torrc custom configuration

success

checking binary version: 0.4.1.5-rc-openssl1.0.2p

Orbot is starting…

- Connecting to control port: 34447
- SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
- SUCCESS - authenticated tor control port.
- Took ownership of tor control port.
- adding control port event handler
- SUCCESS added control port event handler
- NOTICE: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- NOTICE: Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- NOTICE: Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
- NOTICE: Opened DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
- NOTICE: Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9140
- NOTICE: Opened Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9140
- NOTICE: Opening HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8218
- NOTICE: Opened HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8218
- Starting Tor client… complete.
- NOTICE: Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
- NOTICE: Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay

### with OBS bridge

Connected to a relay

- TorService is shutting down
- Using control port to shutdown Tor
- NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8218
- NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
- NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9140
- NOTICE: DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
- sending HALT signal to Tor process
- NOTICE: Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
- Orbot is deactivated
- updating settings in Tor service
- updating torrc custom configuration...
- success.
- checking binary version: 0.4.1.5-rc-openssl1.0.2p
- Orbot is starting…
- Connecting to control port: 35095
- SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
- SUCCESS - authenticated tor control port.
- Took ownership of tor control port.
- adding control port event handler
- SUCCESS added control port event handler
- NOTICE: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- NOTICE: Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- NOTICE: Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
- NOTICE: Opened DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
- NOTICE: Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9140
- NOTICE: Opened Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9140
- NOTICE: Opening HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8218
- NOTICE: Opened HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8218
- Starting Tor client… complete.
- WARN: Managed proxy at '/data/app/org.torproject.torbrowser-My2Pt4nxrL-huBnRYMGrBg==/lib/arm64/libObfs4proxy.so' reported: error: "/data/app/org.torproject.torbrowser-My2Pt4nxrL-huBnRYMGrBg==/lib/arm64/libObfs4proxy.so": executable's TLS segment is underaligned: alignment is 8, needs to be at least 64 for ARM64 Bionic
- WARN: Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 6
- TorService is shutting down
- Using control port to shutdown Tor
- NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8218
- NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
- NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9140
- NOTICE: DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
- sending HALT signal to Tor process
- Orbot is deactivated

### and with MEEK

TorService is shutting down

- Orbot is deactivated
- updating settings in Tor service
- updating torrc custom configuration...
- success.
- checking binary version: 0.4.1.5-rc-openssl1.0.2p
- Orbot is starting…
- Connecting to control port: 33209
- SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
- SUCCESS - authenticated tor control port.
- Took ownership of tor control port.
- adding control port event handler
- SUCCESS added control port event handler
- NOTICE: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- NOTICE: Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- NOTICE: Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
- NOTICE: Opened DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
- NOTICE: Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9140
- NOTICE: Opened Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9140
- NOTICE: Opening HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8218
- NOTICE: Opened HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8218
- Starting Tor client… complete.
- WARN: Managed proxy at '/data/app/org.torproject.torbrowser-My2Pt4nxrL-huBnRYMGrBg==/lib/arm64/libObfs4proxy.so' reported: error: "/data/app/org.torproject.torbrowser-My2Pt4nxrL-huBnRYMGrBg==/lib/arm64/libObfs4proxy.so": executable's TLS segment is underaligned: alignment is 8, needs to be at least 64 for ARM64 Bionic
- WARN: Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 6